# Keras LSTM: Error when checking model input dimension

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I am a new user of keras, and trying to implement a LSTM model. For test I declared the model like below, but it fails because of difference of input dimension. Although I found similar problems in this site, I could not find my mistakes by myself.

```
ValueError: 
Error when checking model input: 
expected lstm_input_4 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (300, 100)
```

#### My environment

- python 3.5.2
- keras 1.2.0 (Theano)

#### Code

> ```
> from keras.layers import Input, Dense
> from keras.models import Sequential
> from keras.layers import LSTM
> from keras.optimizers import RMSprop, Adadelta
> from keras.layers.wrappers import TimeDistributed
> import numpy as np
>
> in_size = 100
> out_size = 10
> nb_hidden = 8
>
> model = Sequential()
> model.add(LSTM(nb_hidden, 
>                name='lstm',
>                activation='tanh',
>                return_sequences=True,
>                input_shape=(None, in_size)))
> model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(out_size, activation='softmax')))
>
> adadelta = Adadelta(clipnorm=1.)
> model.compile(optimizer=adadelta,
>               loss='categorical_crossentropy',
>               metrics=['accuracy'])
>
> # create dummy data
> data_size = 300
> train = np.zeros((data_size, in_size,), dtype=np.float32)
> labels = np.zeros((data_size, out_size,), dtype=np.float32)
> model.fit(train, labels)
> ```

#### Edit 1 (not working, after Marcin Możejko's comment)

Thank you Marcin Możejko. But I have a similar error like below. I updated dummy data for check. What is wrong of this code?

> ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected
>   timedistributed_36 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape
>   (208, 1)

```
def create_dataset(X, Y, loop_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(X) - loop_back-1):
        a = X[i:(i+loop_back), :]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(Y[i+loop_back, :])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

data_size = 300
dataset = np.zeros((data_size, feature_size), dtype=np.float32)
dataset_labels = np.zeros((data_size, 1), dtype=np.float32)

train_size = int(data_size * 0.7)
trainX = dataset[0:train_size, :]
trainY = dataset_labels[0:train_size, :]
testX = dataset[train_size:, :]
testY = dataset_labels[train_size:, 0]
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(trainX, trainY)
print(trainX.shape, trainY.shape) # (208, 1, 1) (208, 1)

# in_size = 100
feature_size = 1
out_size = 1
nb_hidden = 8

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(nb_hidden, 
               name='lstm',
               activation='tanh',
               return_sequences=True,
               input_shape=(1, feature_size)))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(out_size, activation='softmax')))
adadelta = Adadelta(clipnorm=1.)
model.compile(optimizer=adadelta,
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(trainX, trainY, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=1)
```

Comment: Please provide imports.

Comment: @j0e1in Sorry, I added full imports.

Comment: I totally misunderstood LSTM. Inputs must be [samples, timestep, features].  I will upload my code after re-implementing.

Comment: Ha - I've just gave the same answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really classic problem with `LSTM` in `Keras`. `LSTM` input shape should be `2d` - with shape `(sequence_length, nb_of_features)`. Additional third dimension comes from examples dimension - so the table fed to model has shape `(nb_of_examples, sequence_length, nb_of_features)`. This is where your problem comes from. Remember that a `1-d` sequence should be presented as a `2-d` array with shape `(sequence_length, 1)`. This should be a input shape of your `LSTM`:

```
model.add(LSTM(nb_hidden, 
           name='lstm',
           activation='tanh',
           return_sequences=True,
           input_shape=(in_size, 1)))
```

And remember to `reshape` your input to appropriate format.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I have a similar error like below. I updated my code. Would you check my code again?

Comment: It seems that there's something wrong with your target. What is its shape?

Comment: here is. print(trainX.shape, trainY.shape) # (208, 1, 1) (208, 1). I suppose seq_length==1 and num_of_features==1

Comment: it's something wrong with these. Why are you using a `LSTM` for sequences of a length `1`?

Comment: For simplicity. My actual dataset suppose dialog-data between human and machine, actual sequence length is longer than one. But I think seq_length == 1 is not a reason of this error..

Comment: You could deal with this error in two ways. First - reshape Y by `Y.reshape((Y.shape[0], 1, Y.shape[1]))`, second -  simply set `return_sequences=False` and use only `Dense` without a `TimeDistributed` wrapper.

Comment: This other thing - `categorical_crossentropy` and `softmax` are not suitable for layers with `1d` output. Try `binary_crossentropy` as a loss and `sigmoid` as an activation function in a last layer. I would also advise you to set `return_sequences=False` and remove `TimeDistributed` wrapper.